# Поиск текста по регулярным выражениям php

Tags: php

Перепробовал все варианты не могу найти решение.Есть строчка "Volvo XC40 (2018) интерьер" собственно нужно найти слово "интерьер" но это слово встречается и верхнем регистре и в нижнем (интерьер, Интерьер, ИНТЕРЬЕР);
Если слова есть то true нет false.

Comment: «Регулярное ворожение» ;) сниму порчу

Comment: У меня deadline :)

Comment: и чего регулярного в вашем слове этом? Чем вас не устраивает простой регистронезависимый поиск подсктроки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам подойдёт регулярное выражение `"/интерьер/ui"`
В коде это будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
$string = 'Volvo XC40 (2018) иНтЕрьЕр';
//Следующая строка вернёт true или false независимо от регистра
$result = preg_match('/интерьер/ui', $string);
```

Вся магия во флагах которые мы добавляем в конец регулярки:
**u** - отвечает за восприятие юникода
**i** - делает регулярное выражение нечуствительным к регистру.

Так же, не забывайте про наличие якорей:
**^** - начало строки
**$** - конец строки

В вашем случае, если известно что искомое значение будет строго в конце строки, можно воспользоваться якорем  **$**

А вообще рекомендую отличный ресурс для тестирования регулярок https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Должно сработать что-то вроде

```
(И|и)(Н|н)(Т|т)(Е|е)(Р|р)(Ь|ь)(Е|е)(Р|р)
```

Но уверен есть более лаконичное решение

Answer (score 0):

выбирайте и старайтесь всегда тестить варианты

```
$str = 'Volvo XC40 (2018) интерЬер';
$cycle = 100000;

function var1($str)
    {
        $r = 0;

        if(mb_strstr($str, 'интерьер') || mb_strstr($str, 'Интерьер') || mb_strstr($str, 'ИНТЕРЬЕР'))
            {
                $r = 1;
            }

        return($r);
    }

function var2($str)
    {
        $r = 0;

        if(mb_stristr($str, 'интерьер'))
            {
                $r = 1;
            }

        return($r);
    }

function var3($str)
    {
        $r = 0;

        if(preg_match('/интерьер/ui', $str))
            {
                $r = 1;
            }

        return($r);
    }

function var4($str)
    {
        $r = 0;

        $str = mb_strtolower($str);

        if(mb_strstr($str, 'интерьер'))
            {
                $r = 1;
            }

        return($r);
    }

function var5($str)
    {
        $r = 0;

        $str = strtr($str,['И'=>'и','Н'=>'н','Т'=>'т','Е'=>'е','Р'=>'р','Ь'=>'ь',]);

        if(mb_strstr($str, 'интерьер'))
            {
                $r = 1;
            }

        return($r);
    }

function var6($str)
    {
        $r = 0;

        //$str = strtr($str,['И'=>'и','Н'=>'н','Т'=>'т','Е'=>'е','Р'=>'р','Ь'=>'ь',]);

        if(strtr($str,['интерьер'=>'','Интерьер'=>'','ИНТЕРЬЕР'=>'',]))
            {
                $r = 1;//echo $str;die;
            }

        return($r);
    }

$start = microtime(true);//запускаем таймер
for($i=0;$i<$cycle;++$i)
    {
        if(var1($str))
            {
                //echo 'true';
            }
    }
echo 'var1 '.(microtime(true) - $start).PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);//запускаем таймер
for($i=0;$i<$cycle;++$i)
    {
        if(var2($str))
            {
                //echo 'true';
            }
    }
echo 'var2 '.(microtime(true) - $start).PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);//запускаем таймер
for($i=0;$i<$cycle;++$i)
    {
        if(var3($str))
            {
                //echo 'true';
            }
    }
echo 'var3 '.(microtime(true) - $start).PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);//запускаем таймер
for($i=0;$i<$cycle;++$i)
    {
        if(var4($str))
            {
                //echo 'true';
            }
    }
echo 'var4 '.(microtime(true) - $start).PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);//запускаем таймер
for($i=0;$i<$cycle;++$i)
    {
        if(var5($str))
            {
                //echo 'true';
            }
    }
echo 'var5 '.(microtime(true) - $start).PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);//запускаем таймер
for($i=0;$i<$cycle;++$i)
    {
        if(var6($str))
            {
                //echo 'true';
            }
    }
echo 'var6 '.(microtime(true) - $start).PHP_EOL;
```